# How to speed up string splitting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino, pyserial

I am receiving data from an Arduino with a Tkinter GUI and need to receive 8 different values at 20 samples per second and graph them. I am plotting 4 on one graph and 4 on another graph. The code on the Arduino side works fine and is sending at the correct rate using the following format.

```
Serial.println(String(val1) + "," + String(val2) + ...
```

On the Python side I am receiving and graphing like this:

```
def update_graph(self, i):
    self.xdata.append(i)
    while (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    x = self.arduinoData.readline()
    split_data = x.split(",")
    print split_data[1]
    self.ydata1.append(int(split_data[0]))
    self.ydata2.append(int(split_data[1]))
    self.ydata3.append(int(split_data[2]))
    self.ydata4.append(int(split_data[3]))
    self.ydata5.append(int(split_data[4]))
    self.ydata6.append(int(split_data[5]))
    self.ydata7.append(int(split_data[6]))
    self.ydata8.append(int(split_data[7]))
    self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata1)
    self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata2)
    self.line3.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata3)
    self.line4.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata4)
    self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.ydata1), max(self.ydata4))
    self.ax1.set_xlim(min(self.xdata), max(self.xdata))
    self.line5.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata5)
    self.line6.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata6)
    self.line7.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata7)
    self.line8.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata8)
    self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.ydata5), max(self.ydata8))
    self.ax2.set_xlim(min(self.xdata), max(self.xdata))
    if i >= self.points - 1:
        self.running = False
        self.ani = None
    return self.line1,
    return self.line2,
    return self.line3,
    return self.line4,
    return self.line5,
    return self.line6,
    return self.line7,
    return self.line8,
```

This has proved to be way too slow to keep up with the incoming data. Is there a faster way receive and parse the data?

Comment: I doubt that receiving and parsing the data is the slowest part.

Comment: You could send that data in a packed binary format and unpack it with the `struct` module.

Comment: @gre_gor even when i run it with out the plot commands it lags behind significantly

Comment: Are you aware that any code after the first `return` will never execute?

Comment: What does `set_data` do? My guess is that it is an expensive function call, since the actual splitting takes just a couple microseconds.

Comment: set_data sets the line data to be graphed by the animation function that i am using with matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @gre_gor that the parsing is not the slowest part. A while back I was doing a similar project and found that setting the arduino to a higher serial speed did the trick.

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that is all I have. Reducing the data sent by the arduino is always a good idea.

Comment: I am reading the position of 4 different linear actuators and from a sensor related to each actuator so that isn't a viable solution for me thank you for the suggestions though